# How should I pose a request about displaying data for this MySQL query with the AND operator?

Tags: mysql, operator-keyword

Here is the teachers request with his following query as the answer:

["Q12. Display all employees **working for departments 10 and 60**."

```
mysql> select last_name, department_id
> from employees
> where department_id = 10 or department_id = 60;]

This is the result:



+-----------+---------------+
| last_name | department_id |
+-----------+---------------+
| Hunold    |            60 |
| Ernst     |            60 |
| Lorentz   |            60 |
| Whalen    |            10 |
+-----------+---------------+
```

In my opinion, a better question considering the information a person would want to display would be this:  "Display all the employees working for departments 10 and display all of the employees working for department 60."  Under the questions current construction, it seems that he is asking to display only the employees who work for both departments, ie, employees who work for both 60 and 10 at the same time (or at least at different times during the day).

Here's the table desc:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Employee_id    | decimal(6,0) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| First_Name     | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Last_Name      | varchar(25)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Email          | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Phone_Number   | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Hire_Date      | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Job_Id         | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Salary         | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Commission_Pct | decimal(2,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Manager_Id     | decimal(6,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Department_Id  | decimal(4,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Maybe I'm missing something here.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's your question? How to interpret your homework?

Comment: `working for departments 10 and 60`, do you mean *both on 10 AND 60* or *atleast 10 or 60*?

Comment: He wanted us to display employees that work for department 10 and display employees that work for department 60.  It seems that saying "Display all employees working for departments 10 and 60" would be saying "Display all employees who work for both departments at the same time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Under the questions current construction, it seems that he is asking to display only the employees who work for both departments, ie, employees who work for both 60 and 10 at the same time (or at least at different times during the day).*

Except, an employee **can't** work in two departments with the given table structure (assuming it's normalized).

Have you tried:

```
... where department_id = 10 AND department_id = 60
```

Comment: `where department_id = 10 AND department_id = 60` will not return any single record because a `department_id` can have only and *only one* value on every row.

Comment: @JW. That's the point I was trying to convey and may have done so poorly.

Comment: NJK, why with the table structure can an employee not work for two separate departments?  Why can department_id only have one value for every row?  I apologize, I'm new at this obviously.

Comment: @user2031110 If you're in a formal database class, you'll learn about this through the process of normalization. In [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), each column can only have one value. Given the structure you provided, it's assumed each employee can only have one value. If an employee had more than one department, there would be two more tables (`department` & `employeeDepartment`)

Comment: Thank you all very much for your responses.  I think I need a database design course.  This course I'm taking is just SQL queries with no design aspect (no pre-requisite course required).  I feel like it's putting the cart before the horse, or they should at least be taught at the same time.  I don't recall discussing 1nf or 2nf, etc during our first two classes.  I'm trying to supplement the course with the SQL visual quickstart guide.  It seems I'm learning more from that course, and now this site, than from the actual course I'm taking.  C'est la vie.  Thank you guys again.

Comment: @user2031110 It sounds like you're definitely heading in the right direction. I would recommend that you take [this free online class](http://class2go.stanford.edu/db/Winter2013) or [this one](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-830-database-systems-fall-2010/index.htm) that should give you exactly what you should learn.